# how to show a sitecore treelist in an aspx as an control

Tags: asp.net, controls, sitecore

There is an very cool tree list type in sitecore.

how could i use it like a control and set it in my asp.net page?

Also need to know how to set the source of that control and also need to get what user selected.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the control Sitecore is using to build a custom Treelist you should consider getting a license for Telerik controls. Sitecore uses mostly Telerik controls to get the UI they have on the backend.
They use the RadTreeList for their content tree.

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/treelist/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx

Any additional questiom you've asked in your question are answered on the Telerik demo environment.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but my dev environment is based in sitecore, so i just need to bring that controls into an aspx page,even they could have the same looking. is this possible ?

Comment: No, its not possible. It's tightly hooked into Sitecore. I would recommend trying to reproduce it with the Telerik option Younes provided. I've built a multilist on the front-end before and it really just involved a list on the left and one on the right and using jQuery to move items. A treelist would be a bit harder.

Comment: Agreed, the tree-list is customised for the content editor, with all the hooks and events that are needed to make it work as a field-type. Having it running on your web page would throw all sorts of errors.